# Laravel 8 image not showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using `Laravel 8`.

Trying to show image from `storage/app/subject_image/` path but it doesn't display.

Below is my code on `blade`

```
<img src="{{asset("storage/subject_image/$data->subject_image")}}" alt="">
```

also i have inspected element on chrome its showing right path and right image name still its not showing. below is the inpsect element screenshot

[image]

Comment: Where is your image located ? on `public` folder or on `storage` folder?

Comment: its not in public... its storage

Comment: did you run `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: No i dont know about it... its my first laravel project.. i am beginner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Important Note**

> **storage folder** is not **publicly accessible** from the **web browser** and because of that we will have to create a **symbolic link**

**what is symbolic link ?**

> you can say symbolic link as `alias` or `pointer` to your `path directory`

**Where you can configure symbolic links?**

> You may configure symbolic links in your `filesystems` configuration
> file that is located at path **config/filesystems.php**

**Now lets configure symbolic link**

suppose we have a image file located in `storage/app/folder1/img.jpg`

**Now lets configure symbolic link for the above path -**

**Step 1**: open `config/filesystems.php` and configure custom symbolic link

`public_path('my_custom_symlink_1') => storage_path('app/folder1'),`

[image]

**Step 2** : Now run `Artisan command`

> php artisan **storage:link**

Just configuring symbol link in filesystems won't work , you will have to run `php artisan storage:link` to create/active the symbolic link.

**Step 3** : Now you can access you target file in browser using symbolic link

`<img src="{{asset("my_custom_symlink_1/img.jpg")}}" >`

Answer (score 0):

The flowing 2 steps Work for me.

Step 1. Delete storage folder in `public/storage` Directory then

Step 2. Run this command `php artisan storage:link`