# laravel missing file after image upload

Tags: php, laravel

I want to upload a image to a sub directory (public/uploads). after submit it returns successful but it doesn't save the image

```
public function storeMedia(Request $request)
{
 $file = $request->file('productImage');
 $name = trim($file->getClientOriginalName());
 $folder = uniqid() . '_' . now()->timestamp;
 $file->storeAs('uploads/'.$folder, $name, ['disk' => 'public']);

 return $folder;
}
```

it returns `60dc27eb0eb92_1625040875` which is want I need but I can't find the uploaded file

Comment: you have folder public/uploads/$folder ?

Comment: I believe it has stored it in the Storage folder.

Comment: @workservice thanks, I been able to locate it but I it stored in public/uploads not Storage folder

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков yes I have a public/uploads folder

Comment: You specified that it should be in the `public` disc, so it will be in `/storage/app/public/uploads`.

Comment: On your `config/filesystems.php` file, search for `public_uploads` and update the root to public_path() . '/uploads' and that must do the trick

Comment: @Qirel my bad, I'm new to laravel. I actually want it in ```/public/uploads``` not in ```/storage/app/public/uploads``` how can go about it?

Comment: Can i post it as an answer and mark it correct so others can read it too ? @DanielMordi

Comment: @workservice yes you can

Answer (score -2, accepted):

On your `config/filesystems.php` file, search for `public_uploads` and update the `root` to `public_path() . '/uploads'` and that must do the trick

Comment: @Daniel Mordi remember this is not a good approach. This way all your files will be directly uploaded in public folder and it will have security flaws if you dont want all files to publicly accessible.

Comment: There is a way to bypass this and put them in Storage as well

Comment: @workservice And why would you do it that way, instead of just using the native public disc with Laravel? Storing them outside public, and using a symlink is the best and standard practice for a reason..

Answer (score 3):

By default laravel stores file in `storage` folder. If you want your image file need to be accessible publicly then you need to create `symbolic link`.

refer this [Laravel public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

1. put the folder link path in `config/filesystems.php`

> public_path('storage/uploads') => storage_path('app/public/uploads')

2. Run artisan command to create symbolic link

> php artisan storage:link

Here you can refer my another detailed answer for symbolic link [uploading file publicly accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64096668/laravel-blade-image-not-showing/64107263#64107263)